# Animated Text Images in C

Tags: c, command-line, animation

I have to write a text image program in C for a class. Nothing complicated just write an image using text.

In regards to this: towel.blinkenlights.nl, how can I animate my text?

Comment: Probably you should try to explain a bit more in detail what you want to achieve and what the problem is.

Comment: I have to write a program that displays text as an image. Like 

printf("    ******    \n");
printf("   ********   \n");
printf("     ***      \n");

and so on. 

However I am curious how to animate the text, like this guy did if you open up your Terminal and type this in: towel.blinkenlights.nl

Comment: to hlovdal's point: terminal (with or without curses?) or gui (which one? Xlib?, Qt?, SVGAlib? Windows?)?

Comment: That link doesn't work. Also what @hlovdal said.

Comment: `$ towel.blinkenlights.nl
-bash: towel.blinkenlights.nl: command not found`

Comment: You probably mean telnet://towel.blinkenlights.nl

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong one:

telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl

Thanks nmuntz

This is going to be compiled in Terminal without curses

Comment: I imagine all he is doing is clearing the terminal and then printing out a page of text and then waiting a few 100 ms. Then repeat. The drawing of the text is an art for the brave and skilled. I imagine the code is about 10 lines long.

Comment: What search terms or resources can I use to learn how this can be coded?

Comment: If you like towel.blinkenlights.nl, you'll love the Yahoo Answers question about it: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090824065507AAB7Y0w

Answer (score 2):

What platform is this for?
If you want something multiplatform, I would suggest you use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

If its just for Windows, you can probably use conio.h and graphics.h among others.
I found [this](http://computergraphics.dipinkrishna.info/) which seem to have some basic drawing/animating examples in C using some Windows headers. Be advised that this is extremely unportable code and Windows specific.

Update: I also found [this](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/27010/download.aspx) which includes a few examples in using graphics.h

Comment: I do not want graphics to be displayed, but using text characters to look like graphics.

Comment: ncurses and conio are for exactly that. Well, not just for that, but they are ways to manipulate on-screen characters with much more control than by simply printing lines. One thing they can do is "animate" characters.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to show you how to animate something.  This is exactly what that Star Wars animation is.  It's a gigantic text file split up into individual frames.  Read the FAQ at the [Star Wars ASCIImation page](http://www.asciimation.co.nz/) to find out more about it.

The general idea is that you have a set of frames.  Each frame contains one image in the animation.  You clear the screen, show a frame, and then wait for some time period.  Do that over and over, and you have a text animation.

So first you create a file with your frames.  Call it frames.txt.  To allow variable-length frames, we follow each frame by a line that begins with **@!** followed by the number of animation ticks that frame should stay on the screen.  For example, if you're drawing at 15 frames per second and the line is **@! 15**, then the frame will be on screen for 1 second (15 ticks).

```
+---------+
| frame 1 |
+---------+
@! 15
.-----------.
| frame 2   |
|           |
`-----------'
@! 15
+-------------+
| frame 3     |
|             |
|             |
|             |
+-------------+
@! 15
.-----------.
| frame 4   |
|           |
.-----------.
@! 15
+---------+
| frame 5 |
+---------+
@! 3
+---------+
|  rame 5 |
+---------+
@! 3
+---------+
|   ame 5 |
+---------+
@! 3
+---------+
|    me 5 |
+---------+
@! 3
+---------+
|     e 5 |
+---------+
@! 3
+---------+
|       5 |
+---------+
@! 3
+---------+
|         |
+---------+
@! 3
```

Then compile and run this program.  On Linux or OSX, I just save it as *text_animate.cpp* and run *make text_animate*.  On Windows maybe the only thing you'll have to do is change the line that says system("clear") to system("cls"), but I don't know for sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

const char *FRAME_DELIM = "@!";
unsigned int FRAME_DELIM_LEN = strlen(FRAME_DELIM);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if( argc != 2 ) {
        std::cout << "Usage: text_animate <frames file>\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string frames_fn = argv[1];
    struct timespec sleep_time = {0, 1000000000 / 15}; // 15 fps

    std::ifstream file_stream;
    file_stream.open(frames_fn.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    if( !file_stream.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open [" << frames_fn.c_str() << "]\n";
        return -1;
    }

    std::string frame_line;
    unsigned int frame_ticks = 0;
    while( true ) {
            system("clear");

            bool is_frame_delim = false;
            do {
                getline(file_stream, frame_line);
                if( file_stream.fail() && file_stream.eof()) {
                    file_stream.clear();
                    file_stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

                    getline(file_stream, frame_line);
                }
                else if( file_stream.fail() ) {
                    std::cout << "Error reading from file.\n";
                    break;
                }

                is_frame_delim = strncmp(frame_line.c_str(),FRAME_DELIM,
                                         FRAME_DELIM_LEN) == 0;
                if( !is_frame_delim ) {
                    std::cout << frame_line << "\n";
                }
            } while( !is_frame_delim );

        frame_ticks = atoi(&(frame_line.c_str()[FRAME_DELIM_LEN + 1]));

        while( frame_ticks-- > 0 ) {
                    nanosleep(&sleep_time, NULL);
        }
    }

    file_stream.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Then just run **./text_animate frames.txt**.  Press CTRL-C to exit since it loops forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use external libraries, [AALib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) looks like it would help. If not, you could probably use the system() function and pass "cls" (I'm assuming Windows here. For Linux or Mac, use "clear"):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef WIN32
    system("cls");
#else
    system("clear");
#endif
```

After that, it should be a simple job to print out a frame and wait until it's time to print the next one.